# Flask Project Structure Change

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Hello I have a finished Flask/Flask-SqlAlchemy app working correctly but I wanted to reorganize its structure according to:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/

My working project has the following structure and files:

```
folder:monkeyMeRoundTwo:
    -app.py
    -config.py
    -models.py
    -monkeyDB.db
    -app_test.py
    folder:templates: 
         -edit.html
         -friends.html
         -layout.html
         -login.html
         -myProfile.html
         -profile.html
         -register.html
         -users.html
     folder:static:
          folder:css
          folder:images
```

My app.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, \
    url_for, request, session, flash

from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

# local
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///monkeyDB.db'

# heroku
#import os
app.config.from_object('config.BaseConfig')

#app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from models import *

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return render_template('login.html')
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('friendList'))

.......rest of views


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My config.py file:

```
import os

class BaseConfig(object): 
  SECRET_KEY = "kjdsbfkjgdf78sft"
```

My models.py file:

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

class users(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "Users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    userName = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    userEmail = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    userPhone = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    userPass = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, userName, userEmail, userPhone, userPass):

        self.userName = userName
        self.userEmail = userEmail
        self.userPhone = userPhone
        self.userPass = userPass

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(self.id, self.userName, self.userEmail, self.userPhone)


class friendships(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "Friendships"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)
    friend_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)

    userR = db.relationship('users', foreign_keys='friendships.user_id')
    friendR = db.relationship('users', foreign_keys='friendships.friend_id')

    def __init__(self, user_id, friend_id):

        self.user_id = user_id
        self.friend_id = friend_id  

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(self.user_id, self.friend_id)


class bestFriends(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "BestFriends"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)
    best_friend_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)

    user = db.relationship('users', foreign_keys='bestFriends.user_id')
    best_friend = db.relationship('users', foreign_keys='bestFriends.best_friend_id')

    def __init__(self, user_id, best_friend_id):

        self.user_id = user_id
        self.best_friend_id = best_friend_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(self.user_id, self.best_friend_id)
```

My app_tests.py file:

```
import os
import app
import unittest
import tempfile   

class AppTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.db_fd, app.app.config['DATABASE'] = tempfile.mkstemp()
        app.app.config['TESTING'] = True
        self.app = app.app.test_client()

    def tearDown(self):
        os.close(self.db_fd)
        os.unlink(app.app.config['DATABASE'])

    def test_index_page(self):
        rv = self.app.get('/')
        assert 'Friends' in rv.data

...........rest of tests


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

As I mentioned everything works fine and the tests pass all ok but when I attempt to follow the example on:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/

and change the project to the following structure:

Structure/organization:

```
folder:monkeyMeRT:
        -runserver.py
        folder:monkeyMeRT:
              -__init__.py
              -views.py
              -config.py
              -models.py
              -monkeyDB.db
              -app_test.py
              folder:templates: 
                   -edit.html
                   -friends.html
                   -layout.html
                   -login.html
                   -myProfile.html
                   -profile.html
                   -register.html
                   -users.html
              folder:static:
                   folder:css
                   folder:images
```

runserver.py file:

```
from monkeyMeRT import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

**init**.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, \
    url_for, request, session, flash

from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

# local
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///monkeyDB.db'

# heroku
#import os
app.config.from_object('config.BaseConfig')

#app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from models import *

import monkeyMeRT.views
```

views.py file:

```
from monkeyMeRT import app

.......here go all the views/functions
```

models.py file:

```
from monkeyMeRT import db
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

........here go the db classes
```

config.py file:

```
import os

class BaseConfig(object): 
  SECRET_KEY = "kjdsbfkjgdf78sft"
```

After changes I end up with errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from models import *
  File "/Users/alex/Desktop/PY/monkeyMeRT/monkeyMeRT/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from monkeyMeRT import db
ImportError: No module named monkeyMeRT
```

I guess I haven't interpreted the example correctly. Would anyone be able to help me out with this I am new to Flask(started learning a month ago) and would like to have an efficient setup of the project with config and views separated like in the example:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/

Help is very much appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The traceback is telling you that monkeyMeRT is not a package. To fix this:

1. Be sure to name your project folder monkeyMeRT
2. monkeyMeRT needs to contain a file called `__init__.py`

That init file doesn't have to contain anything, it just needs to exist so that Python knows to treat the directory as a Python package.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There was a typo in my question . The changed project folders are named "monkeyMeRT" and it does include  __init__.py   But you are saying i should not rename the app.py as in the example documentation. Should I then leave the app.py and create an empty "__init__.py" file ?

Comment: @AlExTsm If you intend to rename app.py to `__init__.py` that is a good approach that's commonly used. One way or another, you'll need to have *something* called `__init__.py` in order for the dir to be treated as a package.

Comment: @AlExTsm On closer examination... the traceback appears to apply to the original configuration. Do you have a traceback related to your new layout?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you. My original configuration does not produce any type of error. But I was told it was messy to not separate the setup/config from the views. so I applied the changes described in the question which are the ones producing the error. My original configuration just with app.py, config.py and models.py works fine. But when I create the configuration with the runserver.py, '__init__.py', views.py, config.py and models.py , then I get the error. Sorry if I am repeating myself and not answering your question. I am not sure if I am explaining my self correctly